# misunderstanding how the threads work

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, threadpool

I have a problem, big problem with threads in `vb.net`

First of all I want to tell that I didn't work with threads before (just on the school), I read lot of pages about it, but none of them could help me for my problem.

My main question here is understand the logic, and after if is possible, solve the problem that I have, both are related, then I going to explain the problem.

The code hasn't comments and/or documentation related, and is a program developed lot of years ago and the guy that did this is not working on the office, nobody knows how it works :S

I have a list called listOfProccess, and when is only 1 works fine.

in the callback function in `QueueUserWorkItem` fill the information about `p`, then execute the thread, I suppose

That list contain an array with information type

```
listOfProccess[].type = 'a/b/c/d/e/f/g/'
```

also the list include an ID.

Code:

```
If listOfProccess.Count > 0 Then

    Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1, 1)

    Threading.ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(4, 4)


    For Each p In listOfProccess
        Try

            Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New Threading.WaitCallback(Object p.function))


        Catch e As Exception
            sendMail("mail@mail", "alerts@mail.ie", "", e.StackTrace)
        End Try
    Next
```

Problems: 
I have two problems here:

1. Sometimes execute an item in the list i.e. 'a' in a infinite loop, and expends all resources of the machine, but if i close and restart again, works, I didn't know if is a problem with the threads or not, sincerely I think that is other thing, because this problem starts two or tree weeks ago, and the program still running during a year.
2. This one i think is related about threads, if I have two (or more) p on the list like this:

   `p[1].type = 'a/b/c/d/e/f/g/'`
   `p[1].ID = 1`

   `p[2].type = 'ww/xx/ff/yy/aa/rr/'` 
   `p[2].ID =2`

when the system execute something like this, the way that it follows is 'random' ie. takes for the first one, `a, b,c` and after this it does `ww`, and come back to the first. the problem is bigger if I have more items in the list, like 4 or 5; this is not a very big problem, because the program works, it not works 100% fine, but works, is more to try the understand why it works on this way.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: It may sound harsh, but the best option you have is to delete everything and restart from scratch. You need to evaluate everything the program has to do and how it must be done, and even if you think you have everything under control, another person's code will fail whenever you don't expect. Anyway, good luck, you will need it.

Comment: @EduardoSoriano start from 0 is not a valid option, is a very big and complex project which developed was a few months.

Comment: Fire-and-forget threading is never not a problem.  It works when the Sun is shining and you've got the wind in your back.  But it always rains sooner or later.  You'll need to do much more work to diagnose the real problem, at a minimum you'll need to add tracing so you can see what is going on.

Comment: that's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 1):

The second problem is a `race condition` problem, as you can't guarantee the order of the execution for the threads, there is a non-zero probability that your threads will replace each other's values. There are a lot of wayss to solve this issue: algorythms (either lock-oriented and lock-free), synchronization techniques and so on, and there is no `silver-bullet` solution for this.

First problem is unclear for me, as I can't understand what exactly do you mean by `a infinite loop` - may be this can happen if you link items to deleted (from other thread) ones and there is no way to go out of your task, as the links in a list are broken. This still should be solved with sychronization.

I think your should start with MSDN articles or some book about multithreading in general, and after that you should split your program step by step for a small parts you understand.

Update:

`p.function` - about the infinite loop you should consider the code of this delegate. If there is a condition to restart work, you should check a recursion limit. For example, if there is [an optimistic locking algorythm](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt), your code can find out that the update it tried isn't valid, and *restart* it. And if the links are broken, it will never end it's task, and will stay forever in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks about the first problem,  I will have a look on that, about the second, about the `infinite loop` when execute A and finish, restart with a, and a again and again, i don't know if I explain the problem correctly. and yes I have to study about multithreading. thanks.

Comment: @TiGreX Updated the answer, Try to investigate the `p.function` - I think the problem is there.